# Best deployment strategy for perforce server database

Tags: perforce

Is there a recommended strategy for using perforce server backend database? I believe internally is using HSQLDB, will that be good enough for production? Or is it advisable to use MySQL (i can't find a proper link explaining how to achieve this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Perforce server manages its own database and does not require (or support) third-party database software.  Every production Perforce instance that's out there uses the built-in database.